# Envió de mensajes a numeros de whatsapp desde Python

Tags: python, whatsapp, pywhatkit

Agradezco la colaboración o sugerencia que puedan ofrecerme para la creación de una rutina desde R o Python para el envió de mensajes a numeros Whatsapp

Intente con una rutina sugerida:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.start_server()

# Usamos Un try-except
try: 

  # Enviamos el mensaje

  pg.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+57XXXXXXXXXX",  
                                  "Mensaje De Prueba desde python") 

  print("Mensaje Enviado") 

  

except: 

  print("Ocurrio Un Error")
```

Esta rutina es en lenguaje Python, se crea el ambiente virtual para la instalación del paquete, sin embargo al intentar importarlo no lo permite ya que genera un error.

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5d93f787c1aa> in <module>
      1 # Importamos el Módulo
      2 
----> 3 import pywhatkit
      4 #pywhatkit.start_server()
      5 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py in <module>
     14 from pywhatkit.misc import info, playonyt, search, show_history, web_screenshot
     15 from pywhatkit.sc import cancel_shutdown, shutdown
---> 16 from pywhatkit.whats import (
     17     open_web,
     18     sendwhatmsg,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywhatkit/whats.py in <module>
      5 from urllib.parse import quote
      6 
----> 7 import pyautogui as pg
      8 
      9 from pywhatkit.core import core, exceptions, log

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py in <module>
    247 
    248 try:
--> 249     import mouseinfo
    250 
    251     def mouseInfo():

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py in <module>
    221             raise
    222 
--> 223     _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
    224 
    225     def _linuxPosition():

/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    667         except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
    671 

KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5d93f787c1aa> in <module>
      1 # Importamos el Módulo
      2 
----> 3 import pywhatkit

Comment: Buenas tardes christian el error que me arroja es al importar el paquete pywhatkit

Comment: Agrega el error completo a la pregunta. Además, recuerda tener instalado `pywhatkit` en tu entorno virtual

Comment: Que S.O. estás usando?

Comment: El mensaje dice que la variable DISPLAY no existe en el ambiente desde el cual ejecutas el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar el paquete desde la linea de comandos con:

```
pip install pywhatkit
```

El el código debes eliminar la linea que dice:
pywhatkit.start_server()

ese comando es para controlar remotamente el ordenador, desde otro que esté conectado a la misma red local.

Además debes agregar un tercer parámetro que es el tiempo de espera para que presione enviar. En mi equipo le toma entre 20 y 30 segundos está listo.
Sino la pantalla se quedará con el mensaje escrito y nunca lo enviará, porque el  fué enviado antes que la pantalla del navegador esté lista.

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+57XXXXXXXXXX",  
                                  "Mensaje De Prueba desde python",30)
```

Tambien puedes completarlo con:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+57XXXXXXXXXX",  
                                  "Mensaje De Prueba desde python", 30, true, 15)
```

Donde true es cerrar la pestaña activa del navegador
y 15 es el tiempo de espera hasta cerrar la pestaña.

Espero haberme dado a entender.

Saludos.